# Recording 2 way call causing exception

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am working on an android app and I want to record two way audio of a call. I am performing the test via the emulator by doing a gsm call and then pressing the start record button from my app.

I keep on getting the following error though:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
```

Below is how I am performing the record:

```
private void startRecording()
    {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        try
        {
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
        }

    }
```

I read that some device don't allow two way audio recording and that in that case you should default back to using the MIC to do the recording, however, I assume that this wouldn't be the reason for the emulator.

Thanks for any help you can provide,

Comment: _"I assume that this wouldn't be the reason for the emulator"_. I wouldn't bet money on that. Do you have any more logs from when you call `prepare` and `start`?

Comment: Nothing seems to get logged, I do have another problem though since updating the SDK and ADT tools that when I place a call to the emulator the ADB disconnects from the emulator. I guess that's why there are no logs

Comment: Make sure you added appropriate *permission* into manifest file.

Comment: Ah that's it, I forgot to add the AUDIO_RECORD permission. Its a bit strange no exception is thrown telling me that there is no permission for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), you can find:

> Note: Currently, MediaRecorder does not work on the emulator.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Ah thanks. I did read that document but never noticed that warning. A bit annoying that it doesn't work on the emulator as it means I've got to keep making phone calls to my mobile which can get expensive during debugging.